# pandas create a column with space based on the length of another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I want to create a new column based on length.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [7,5,3]})
test['space_word'] =  f"{' ' * (test['col1'])} : left blank"
```

However, got error:

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

The desired output should be:

```
col1   space_word
   7           : left blank   
   5         : left blank
   3       : left blank
```

**Solved:**
Using `transform()`

```
test['space_word'] =  test.col1.transform(lambda x: f"check {' ' * x} : left blank")

   col1                  space_word
0     7  check         : left blank
1     5    check       : left blank
2     3      check     : left blank
```

Comment: Try `test["space_word"] = test["col1"].apply(lambda x: f'{" "*x}: left blank')`

Comment: There is some weird behaviour when creating spaces on the left side. For example this ``test["space_word"] = ["\x0c"*val+": left blank" for val in df.col1.values] `` works fine on the right side, but this ``test["space_word"] = ["\x0b"*val+": left blank" for val in test.col1.values] `` gives a strange output (The spaces are their, but not shown).